# Angle between 2 points

Tags: calculus

Given the following image:

$\hskip{1.5 in}$ [image]

Supposing $A(100, 300)$ and $B(300, 100)$, how can I find the angle $\alpha$ between A and B?

On a side note, what's the main difference between a point and a vector? translating a point to a vector is as simple as Point = Vector? Sometimes I find articles where the terms are interchangable

Comment: Your image shows that you are asking for the angle at the origin

Comment: ok, how should I edit my main question in order to describe that I want to know angle alpha? Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: You may have been taught about the dot product, perhaps something like $$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}=\left\|\mathbf{a}\right\| \, \left\|\mathbf{b}\right\| \cos \theta$$ so how might you apply that here?

Comment: so it's $\theta = \arccos((\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b})/(\left\|\mathbf{a}\right\| \, \left\|\mathbf{b}\right\|))$ ?

Comment: Yes (though you might want to take care about the sign)

Comment: Coming from a google search, this answer being a "hint" and not an actual answer to the question is frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

The [Atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function in most computer languages will take the coordinates of a point and give the angle from the origin to that point.  If you take Atan2$(B_x,B_y)-$Atan2$(A_x,A_y)$ you will have it, to within multiples of $2\pi$.  If you use the usual arctangent you need to worry about which quadrant you are in.

Points are exactly that, locations in the plane (in 2D).  Vectors are things with a length and a direction.  You can make a correspondence between a point and the vector from the origin to that point, which seems to be what you are doing.  But a vector can also be from (1,2) to (4,8), for example.  This vector has coordinates (3,7).

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding something. Where I have `p1.x = -384`, `p1.y = 0`, `p2.x = -192`, and `p2.y=-332.5537` and doing `A = WorksheetFunction.Atan2(P2.x, P2.y) - WorksheetFunction.Atan2(P1.x, P1.y)`, My `A` value is -5,2360... `A * 2 * 3.1416` is -32,89... I know for a fact the angle is 60 degrees. I'm no where near that if I take the radiant result and convert it to degrees ( A * 180# / PI ).

Comment: This formula seems to work better: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/855541/1146278

Answer (score 2):

Let $A={A_x \choose A_y}$. Then you subtract the angle $\angle A$ (between $A$ and the $x$-axis) from $\angle B$ (the angle between $B$ and the $x$-axis).

Use the inverse of $\tan(\angle A)=\frac{A_y}{A_x}$ to get
$\alpha= \tan^{-1}(\frac{A_y}{A_x})-\tan^{-1}(\frac{B_y}{B_x})$.